# How to hide only one account from my profile?

Tags: support, accounts

Suppose I have 20 accounts on stackexchange.com. Now I want to remove my one account from profile for professional reasons because I don't want to show that I actively participate in a religion or ethnic group.

At the same time, I do not want to delete that account because I want to actively participate in it and also want to keep its score. I just want to remove or hide it from profile.

I would like to hear your advice.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It was not possible back then when the question was posted, but now it is

Go to `Profile` -> `Settings` -> `Hidden Communities`

and click `Hide` to any Visible Communities.

Hiding a community means other users will not see it in your Communities list or Top Network Posts. It does not, however, mean your activity is private.