# Should I create a separate account for non-technical SE sites?

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-accounts

Is it valid on Stack Exchange Network to create multiple accounts for different purposes?

I have this account for technical purposes. Even though I am only mostly active on Stack Overflow, I am connected to two other SE technical sites with the same account.

Now I want to involve myself in other non-technical sites of network. But, for that, I want to create a separate account. With that account, I do not want to link with sites I am linked with this account. Separation of concerns as I learned recently while learning design patterns ;).

I noticed that a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3972324/kennybot) <s>[users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/377214/sonic-the-inclusive-hedgehog)</s> are already doing this. So I do not think this should be an issue. I just wanted to confirm before taking action (learning from [an old mistake](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365145/5779732)).

If yes, please also suggest what precautions I should take. Should I mention the other account in my profile? Is there anything I should do to avoid merging those accounts? Anything else?

Comment: Are you aware that you can hide specific sides from your profile?  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276904/how-to-hide-only-one-account-from-my-profile

Comment: @psubsee2003: I do not want to hide the account/site. I want to create entirely separate account. If necessary/recommended, I will mention other account in profile.

Comment: @psubsee2003 that is not a privacy feature and trivially defeated, it is entirely useless for this purpose.

Comment: Nitpick: the user in your second example isn't using multiple Network accounts, but merely different user names/avatars on different sites.

Comment: @MadScientist I know - but I wanted to make sure the OP (or anyone seeing this question in the future) was aware of the feature.

Comment: Cross-site dupl\*cate: [*Multiple accounts question*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277434/242059) (Meta.SE)

Comment: KennyBOT does not exist to post on other SE sites. It's sole purpose is to act as the chat identity of the chatbot I run. It's posts are meant to get the bot at the rep level needed to be able to chat. Its posts on SO are in a tag I have ignored in my main account. The post on MSE was a single hat answer, rest of the rep it gained from suggested-edits that were approved by others. As long as you don't make these accounts interfere with each other (voting, editing, commenting) you should be good to go. Keep in mind you need separate browsers to not have the accounts merged.

Comment: I've done it. It helps me keep my work and hobbies separate. I'm very careful to keep the accounts from intersecting anywhere.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Should* you? Up to you.

*Can* you? Yes. It's been confirmed more than once ([here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277434/242059), [here by shog9 himself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57685/134069)) that it's okay to have multiple accounts (even on the same site) **provided** you don't use them to do things you couldn't do if you didn't have multiple accounts (like upvoting your own posts, voting on someone else's post more than once, etc.). Within a site, it's best to avoid using more than one account in **any** capacity on the same question (e.g., don't even comment with account B if you've voted or posted or commented with account A). But if you're using your accounts on completely different sites in the SE network, none of that comes up.

Comment: [Too many Shogs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/291658/271865)