# How can I delete any of my Stack Exchange accounts?

Tags: discussion

On my Stack overflow account *Activity* page, when I scroll down, I see all the network sites linked to my account. Is there a possibility to unsubscribe from certain ones that I'm no longer interested in?

[image]

Comment: you can either delete or hide the profiles you're not interested in any more.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account or https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276904/how-to-hide-only-one-account-from-my-profile

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to delete your profile in one of your sites because you are no longer interested, then follow these steps:

I will be taking my Hinduism Stack Exchange profile as an example.

1. Go to the site for which you want to delete your profile.

   [image]
2. Go to your profile page on that site and click "Edit profile and settings".

   [image]
3. Click the "Delete Profile" button.

   [image]

Comment: @Asmoun I actually didn't sacrifice it. Though I probably will, since I don't have any activity there.